# Parsing data into Parent-Child - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, parsing, parent-child

I Am currently working on a little project in Python which produces a lot of messy data.
The data comes from multiple sources and each one *can* return a different data order/format.

**TLDR At the bottom**

I have parsed this data into lists for each line of the results.
However, as mentioned before the data does not come in the same order.

So pulling list item 3 could be a different bit of data on each line. Furthermore, I do not know how many or what the list items will be called.

Here are my lists (Split by Comma):

```
{'region_code': 'MO', 'postal_code': None, 'country_code': 'US', 'isp': 'ISP-Name'}
{'hash': 1234, 'org': 'CompanyName', 'transport': 'tcp', 'data': 'HTTP/1.0 302 Found\r\nLocation'}
{'hash': 4321, 'isp': 'ISP-Name', 'transport': 'tcp', 'data': 'HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server'}
```

And id like to turn it into something like this: (With the rest of the list items of course)

```
Line    -  region_code  -  hash   -  org
1       -  MO           -  N/A    -  N/A
2       -  N/A          -  123456 -  CompanyName
3       -  N/A          -  654321 -  N/A
```

I Currently have this which splits each lines contents into a list item by comma

```
file = open ("filename.txt" , "r")
fileRead = file.readlines()
fileSplit = fileRead.split(",")
file.close()
print (fileSplit[-1])
```

I am then thinking of doing something along the lines of:

```
for x in fileSplit:
    splitItem = fileSplit.split(":")
    #some line to make each string before the : a "parent" and after a "Child"
```

**So here is my issue: (TLDR)**

Is there a way to dynamically create parents and children from list items that change position in the list and may not exist in some lists?

--- From Result 1 we have No List item for 'hash'

--- From Result 2 we have ['hash' : 1234], could it pull. Parent = hash | Child = 1234

--- From Result 3 we have ['hash' : 4321], could it pull. Parent = hash | Child = 4321

--- Parent = hash | Child = 1234, 4321

Comment: Can you just clarify that those are indeed lists and not dictionaries? You've written them out in dictionary format. `{'region_code': 'MO', 'postal_code': None, 'country_code': 'US', 'isp': 'ISP-Name'}
{'hash': 1234, 'org': 'CompanyName', 'transport': 'tcp', 'data': 'HTTP/1.0 302 Found\r\nLocation'}
{'hash': 4321, 'isp': 'ISP-Name', 'transport': 'tcp', 'data': 'HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server'}` If the data is coming in exactly like that, then the implementation is a lot easier.

Comment: I haven't looked into dictionaries,  Each String needs to be analysed separately, but its the data contained between each {}

Comment: So the data looks like this? 
`'region_code': 'MO', 'postal_code': None, 'country_code': 'US', 'isp': 'ISP-Name'
`

Comment: Yeah, I've been reading up and it looks like that may be my answer.
So the three different strings will be three different dictionaries.
Can i then search for the Hash  entry across all 3 dictionaries and it will return similar to what's in the TLDR? 
If so do you want to put something as an answer so i can upvote and mark it as solved :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data is always going to be in this format:

```
'region_code': 'MO', 'postal_code': None, 'country_code': 'US', 'isp': 'ISP-Name'
'hash': 1234, 'org': 'CompanyName', 'transport': 'tcp', 'data': 'HTTP/1.0 302 Found\r\nLocation'
'hash': 4321, 'isp': 'ISP-Name', 'transport': 'tcp', 'data': 'HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server'
```

Then this is a hacky way of getting around parsing it yourself into nice objects.

```
import ast

lines = []
file = open ("filename.txt" , "r")

for line in file.readlines():
    lines.append(ast.literal_eval("{"+line+"}"))
file.close()


for line in lines:
    for key,value in line.items():
        print(key)
        print (value)
```

Key is the "parent" and value is the "child". The only issue is that I'm not sure how you're going to populate:

```
Line    -  region_code  -  hash   -  org
1       -  MO           -  N/A    -  N/A
2       -  N/A          -  123456 -  CompanyName
3       -  N/A          -  654321 -  N/A
```

Your data has no key, so it's impossible to determine which dict's hash corresponds to whatever line. So if:

```
'hash': 1234, 'org': 'CompanyName', 'transport': 'tcp', 'data': 'HTTP/1.0 302 Found\r\nLocation'
'hash': 4321, 'isp': 'ISP-Name', 'transport': 'tcp', 'data': 'HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server'
```

Results in a `{'hash': [1234, 4321]}`. Which line's hash is that? Unless there's markers in your data denoting where the data belongs or you have multiple datasets that correspond to their own line in your table, it's not possible. If your lines of data correspond to one line then you could do something like this to achieve your TLDR:

```
import ast

lines = []
file = open ("filename.txt" , "r")

for line in file.readlines():
    lines.append(ast.literal_eval("{"+line+"}"))
file.close()

merged_dict = {}
for line_dict in lines:
    for key,value in line_dict.items():
        if key in parsed_dict:
            parsed_dict[key].append(value)
        else:
            parsed_dict[key] = [value]

print (merged_dict)
```

**Output:**

```
{'region_code': ['MO'], 'postal_code': [None], 'country_code': ['US'], 'isp': ['ISP-Name', 'ISP-Name'], 'hash': [1234, 4321], 'org': ['CompanyName'], 'transport': ['tcp', 'tcp'], 'data': ['HTTP/1.0 302 Found\r\nLocation', 'HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server']}
```